# 最大値の要素を、1.2倍にしたいのです

Tags: c

タイトルにもある通り、最大値の要素を1.2倍にしたいのですが、どうすればいいのかがわかりません。
要素 `{87,20,45,38,99,120,28}` の最大値は 120 なので、期待している実行結果は

```
$ ./a.out
激励前: 87 20 45 38 99 120 28 
激励後: 87 20 45 38 99 144 28
```

なのですが、実際に実行を行うと

```
$ ./a.out
激励前: 87 20 45 38 99 120 28 
激励後: 87 20 45 38 99 120 28
```

となってしまいます。

私は以下のようにプログラムを実装したのですが、void関数の定義の仕方がわからなかったので聞いている次第です。

void関数をどのように修正すれば、期待している実行結果が出力されるのでしょうか。
回答よろしくお願いします。

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* 要素数sizeの整数配列aに順に入力する */
void printIntArray(int a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i = i+1) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void bonus(int a[], int size, double x)
{
    int i;
    double max,max2;
    x=1.2;
    max=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<size;i=i+1) {
        if (a[i]>max) {
            max=a[i];
        }
    }max2=x*max;
}

/* 要素数sizeの整数配列aの最大値を x 倍する */

int main(void)
{
    int salaries[] = { 87, 20, 45, 38, 99, 120, 28 };
    int size; 

    size = 7;
    printf("激励前: ");
    printIntArray(salaries, size);

    bonus(salaries,size,1.2);

    printf("激励後: ");
    printIntArray(salaries, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void 関数` なんてものはないし修正丸投げですか。デバッグしましょう。デバッガの使い方覚えましょう。

Comment: `bonus`関数に`max2`の使いをチェックしよう。また、`x`にもう一度`1.2`をアサインするのはなぜですか。

Comment: 関数を使うのであれば、引数と返り値、そして変数のスコープを意識した書き方を覚えた方がよさそうです。参考: https://tcs.c.titech.ac.jp/csbook/c_lang/chap3.html

Comment: 「void関数」とは何を指しているのでしょうか？

Comment: bonus関数です。間違えました。

Comment: 質問文を修正してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void bonus(int a[], int size, double x)
{
    int i;
    double max,max2;
    x=1.2;
    max=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<size;i=i+1) {
        if (a[i]>max) {
            max=a[i];
        }
    }max2=x*max;
}
```

a[i] を何も更新していないため配列 a の内容は変化しませんね。
配列 a の要素の最大値の index を使いましょう。

```
void bonus(int a[], int size, double x)
{
    int k = 0;      // 最大値用の index
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[k]) {
            k = i;  // 大きい値の index で k を更新
        }
    }
    a[k] = (int)(a[k] * x);
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。i番目の要素がk番目の要素より大きい場合には、kにiを代入するというアルゴリズムは思いつきませんでした。とても助かりました。